# Ruby require fails with Not enough space[loadquery failed]

Tags: c++, ruby, swig

I managed to compile ruby 2.0.0 on aix in 64 bit mode and now I am trying to get my swig wrapper around a c++ class to work.

After compiling ruby, `make test` comes back clean and indeed ruby seems to be running fine.
Next step was to compile the extension.

pointing to my new ruby install I created an extconf.rb with the following:

```
require 'mkmf'
create_makefile('wv')
```

wv being the name of the module.
then I ran

```
make
make install
```

which ran clean.
but when I run

```
ruby -e "require 'wv'"
```

I get the following traceback.

```
/blah/blah/ruby/aix/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': load failed - /blah/blah/ruby/aix/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/powerpc-aix6.1.0.0/wv.so. Not enough space[loadquery failed] (LoadError)
```

BTW, I when I used the same swig generated cxx file and followed the same procedure on linux , everything works fine.

Any idea's on were to begin to figure out what is broken?

Comment: I would try an strace

Comment: Looking at the man for strace, it seem like I would attach it to a running process?  Any idea how I would get it to trace just the above one liner?

Comment: aix does not have strace, but has something called truss ...

Comment: using truss at least confirmed that something was wrong with the loading of the library.  I think the message about "space" is misleading. I think ruby is just assuming since it found the file it must be a space issues, but I think the library is not loading because it still has un-resolved symbols caused by incompatible name mangling between the interface code and the library i am trying to wrap.  The interface was compiled using g++, but the library was compiled using xlC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When require fails for any reason other than "no such file",  you need to dig deeper.
In my case the issue was not related to space at all.  In my case the issue was not space but the fact that , while the shared object file could be located, it did not load properly.
The extension attempted to link to an incompatible library.
The extension was compiled using g++, while the library was compiled using xlC.  The mangled names of the two libraries were incompatible.  recompiling the library using g++ solved the problem